# SQLAclhemy INNER JOIN

Tags: sql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I need to create a SQL query using double INNER JOIN, but need find a way in Flask-SQLAlchemy:

This is the original SQL Query:

```
SELECT ip_settings.ip
FROM server 
INNER JOIN network_interfaces ON network_interfaces.id = server.fk_network_interfaces
INNER JOIN ip_settings ON ip_settings.id = network_interfaces.fk_ip_settings
WHERE server.id=6
```

This is the SQLAlchemy format using Session format:

```
from sqlalchemy.engine import create_engine
engine = create_engine('postgresql://username:password@1.1.1.1/imbuedb', echo=True)
connection = engine.connect()
result = connection.execute("SELECT ip_settings.ip FROM server INNER JOIN network_interfaces ON network_interfaces.id = server.fk_network_interfaces INNER JOIN ip_settings ON ip_settings.id = network_interfaces.fk_ip_settings WHERE server.id=6")
```

Can't figure out this double INNER JOIN after looking documentation:
http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/tutorial.html#explicit-join-eagerload

This is the correct format:

```
query = session.query(Model.IpSetting.ip).select_from(Model.Server).join(Model.NetworkInterface).join(Model.IpSetting).filter(Model.Server.id==8)
```

print query

```
SELECT ip_settings.id AS ip_settings_id 
FROM server JOIN network_interfaces ON network_interfaces.id = server.fk_network_interfaces JOIN ip_settings ON ip_settings.id = network_interfaces.fk_ip_settings 
WHERE server.id = :id_1
```

Comment: I'm a little confused, is `ip_settings` a table as well? What does `SELECT ip_settings.ip FROM server` mean ?

Comment: Yes it's a table, it gets the ip field from opsettinhs tables and check joins as they handle the foreign keys association to be able to do the matching